# Antd table duplicate columns

Tags: reactjs, antd

In the below code
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-varahamihira-yqsuds?file=/src/mock.js:228-236

I need some help in looping data in antd table and displaying it without duplicating columns, since array of objects is inside another object I'm not sure how it should be done.
From the above example I need to achieve one column as lastname and two rows for it testing and testing 2

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check whether this what you needed? https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-paper-6n48v1

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thanks, Yes partially I got what I expected, but if need to print also the name in the same table which is outside the mocking array, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please check this updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frost-liqf2o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will work.

```
const _data = tableData.map(({ mocking }) => mocking).flat()
const _dataSource = tableData.map(item => item.name);
const dataSource = _data?.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, name: _dataSource[index ]}));
```

Add Columns like this:

```
const columns = [
 {
   title: "Last Name",
   dataIndex: "lastName",
   key: "lastName"
 },
 {
   title: "Name",
   dataIndex: "name",
   key: "name"
 },
];
```

Return your Antd Table component.

```
return <Table pagination={false} dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes partially I got what I expected, but if need to print also the name in the same table which is outside the mocking array, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, It is possible do you want that will add in the question if you want?

Comment: Yeah, dataTable is an array and it has an id & mocking is an array inside it and it also has an array, so I need to print both in one table.

Comment: @PremKumar, Added updated code, I think it will work Please accept my answer and do upvote if you like it:).